# How to usems-Access database for visual basic 6

Tags: vb6

I am new commer in coding.
I want to create a Student information project where I have to save edit and delete student information.
For this I created seperate forms for add edit delete in vb6.
My problem is: I want to store this in ms-access database.
so can any one tell me how to create ms-access database and add connectivity?
and how to add record in it using vb code?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this tutorial with help you: http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/vb6-access